# As of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier

Tags: java, android, kotlin, enums

I am using enum as a parameter and I am getting this error

> error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
>
> ```
> private final kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1<com.tylertech.newworld.mobility.enum.CustomAlertDialogEvents, kotlin.Unit> itemClicked = null;
> ```

Below Is my enum class

```
 enum class CustomAlertDialogEvents(var resId: Int, val value: Int) {
    ACTION_OPEN_SETTINGS(R.string.open, 0),
    ACTION_CLOSE_SETTINGS(R.string.close, 1)
}
```

And I am using like this

```
private val itemClicked: (CustomAlertDialogEvents) -> Unit
```

Any ideas why this error is coming?

**UPDATE**
Image below shows I am using this convention and it is working for every other case.
[image]

Comment: I think, you shouldn't mix Kotlin and Java. It cannot create a Java class in `enum` package. So, you shouldn't use `CustomAlertDialogEvents` class in Java.

Comment: My entire project is in kotlin .

Comment: `private final kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1<com.tylertech.newworld.mobility.enum.CustomAlertDialogEvents, kotlin.Unit> itemClicked = null;` is in Java. If it was Kotlin, there were no error. Maybe a compiler creates this method? Agree, that is strange.

Comment: You can create a "hello world" project from zero and add these classes. It will compile.

Comment: I think the problem may with use of R.string.open/close leading to generation of Java code in the same package. Perhaps the cases which work don't use it (or only use the standard ones from https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/R.string)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have `enum` as part of your package name. `enum` is also a keyword in java and you cannot use keywords in package names. Rename your package e.g. to `enums`.

Comment: Yes moving to different package name works. But I am having multiple enums  in my enum package and I didn't face this issue before. I don't know why now. As you can see in the image above.

Comment: Yes, kotlin is more relaxed than java when it comes to identfiers. But it is still a good idea to not use keywords as identifiers. I think there's something here that triggers intermediate java code generation without going directly from kotlin to bytecode. For example, an annotation processor.